# onOpen on specific Sheet in AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an `onOpen` execution code but I want it to execute only when a specific sheet is opened (For example on opening `Sheet1` the onOpen function should run.) Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here is what exactly I want to achieve:

1. On open of the spreadsheet, check if the active sheet is sheet1. In case it is then execute a condition within that sheet, as shown below:

> ```
> onOpen()
> {
>     //If the active sheet is "Sheet1" then perform this:
>     //Sheet Execution comes here.
> }
> ```

But here is the problem with above statement:

onOpen will only check once the sheet is opened. I want to check it every time the active sheet is "Sheet1". So for example, initially the user opens the spreadsheet, they land to "Sheet1" Now the condition is checked and output is displayed, but what if user changes the tab to say "Sheet2" and then comes back to "Sheet1". In that case `onOpen()` won't execute. I want to perform my check everytime the user lands or switches to "Sheet1".

Now here's another scenario:

using `onSelectionChange`:

> ```
> onSelectionCHange()
> {
>     //If the active sheet is "Sheet1" then perform this:
>     //Sheet Execution comes here.
> }
> ```

Now this will work everytime user switches to "Sheet1", but here's the problem, even if user switches to different cells in "Sheet1" `onSelectionChange` will be triggered, which is again something undesired. All I want is to only trigger the function each time the tab/sheet is changed to "Sheet1" and not only when the spreadsheet is opened or any selection cell is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation:

To execute a block of code inside the `onOpen` function **only** when you open the spreadsheet file from **Sheet1** then you can construct the following if condition:

```
function onOpen(e) {
const as = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (as == 'Sheet1'){
//code you want to be executed when you open the spreadsheet from Sheet1
}
}
```

---

### Drawback:

The **onOpen** function is only executed when you **open** the **spreadsheet** file. You can't just switch between sheets and expect onOpen to work.

---

## Solution:

To execute a code when switching between different sheets you can instead use `onSelectionChange(e)`. The following example sets the value of the cell A1 of **Sheet1** when you switch from a **different** sheet to **Sheet1**:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  
const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (as.getName() == 'Sheet1'){ 
    as.getRange('A1').setValue("This is Sheet1");
  }
}
```

---

And here is a general code template to execute a code when switching to **Sheet1**:

```
  function onSelectionChange(e) {
      
    const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      if (as.getName() == 'Sheet1'){ 
        // put your code here
      }
    }
```

---

### References:

- [onOpen(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: Will this work if you're switching the spreadsheets? For example currently I am on sheet1 so first time onOpen will work but if I switch between sheets, I don't think that will trigger onOpen?

Comment: @ShivamSahil I just updated my answer regarding that. onOpen function works only when you open the Spreadsheet, not when you switching between sheets.

Comment: Hmm, I see thanks... actually I am looking for something that works while switching between the sheets.

Comment: @ShivamSahil please see my edited answer. The solution part. :)

Comment: I saw your solution... But didn't solve my problem, anyways thanks for the reference.

Comment: @ShivamSahil please explain again what you want so I can modify my answer or accept the answer as it is and post a different question with more clarification on what you need.

Comment: sorry for creating confusion... I have got my solution from your answer thanks!